# Dokan SSH mount and Sublime Text 2

Tags: windows-7, ssh, sublime-text-2, sshfs, dokan

I'm trying to work on a remote project using a mounted SSH using [Dokan](http://dokan.googlecode.com) on Windows 7 and Sublime Text 2. The problem is the file browsing pane works unreliably: it may take ages to "open" a directory in the tree or it may just silently fail to do so.

So the question is: **is there any way to "preload" or "prebrowse" or something like that a mounted SSH file system so that programs like file browsing components of editors are not affected by the connection lag? Or does anyone know of any ST2 specific hack to solve this?**